# Unknown provider AngularJS error

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have this error and I dont know why

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite, $rootScope, AppStart) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      }
      if(window.StatusBar) {
          StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }
      $cordovaSQLite.deleteDB("my.db");
      db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("my.db");
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS preferences (id integer primary key, description string, value string)");

      AppStart.init();
  });
})

.factory("AppStart", function($scope, $cordovaSQLite) {
  var query = "SELECT id, description, value FROM preferences";
  return {
    init: function() {
      var res = "hello";
    }
  }
})
```

When run my code, i get an error 
 ror: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- AppStart

Why do i get an unknown provider even though i hv set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be injecting `$scope` in a factory (service). The way to go would be to change the `$scope` inside a controller or directive and if you want to use some variable from your factory with your `$scope`, just use `$watch` to detect changes in a service variable.

Short version: remove `$scope` from the 'AppStart' factory